# Can't understand how to use PHP DOMDocument::getElementById

Tags: php, html, dom

I wrote this small test code in PHP to try to grasp how DOMDocument::getElementById works. I wrote this way so I can make use of method chaining.

```
<?php
class SMHtmlElement extends DOMElement {

    public function __construct($name, $value = NULL, $namespaceURI = NULL) {
        parent::__construct($name, $value, $namespaceURI);
    }

    public function attr($attribute, $value) {
        if (!empty($attribute)) {
            $this->setAttribute($attribute, $value);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function id($value) {
        $this->attr('id', $value);

        // this doesn't helped.
        @$this->ownerDocument->validate();

        $this->setIdAttribute('id',TRUE);
        return $this;
    }
}

class SMHtmlDocument extends DOMDocument {

    private $body;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct("1.0", "UTF-8");
        $this->validateOnParse = true;
        $this->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>');
        $this->body = $this->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    }

    public final function bodyAdd($element, $beforeElement = NULL) {
        $el = new SMHtmlElement($element);
        if ($beforeElement)
            $beforeElement->insertBefore($el);
        else
            $this->body->appendChild($el);

        return $el;
    }
}

// this search should work it didn't
$dom = new SMHtmlDocument();
$p1 = $dom->bodyAdd('p')->id('foo');
$p = $dom->getElementById('foo');
echo $dom->saveHTML();
var_dump($p);

// when set the ID outside the method, it works.
$p2 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
$p2->setIdAttribute('id',true);
$p = $dom->getElementById('foo');
var_dump($p);

// let's see if both paragraph elements are the same
var_dump($p1->isSameNode($p2));
?>
```

After executing it, I got this output:

```
$> php teste.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body><p id="foo"></p></body></html>
NULL // first var_dump()
object(DOMElement)#4 (0) { // second var_dump()
}
bool(true)
```

As you can see, I've marked the attribute id as ID inside the method id() and it didn't work. But when I called the method setIdAttribute() outside the object, it did work.

Some posts here suggested to use a DTD, but as I trying to generate a HTML5, as far as I know, HTML5 is not based on DTDs. I also know that I could use XPath to find the id I want, but I am really trying to understand why my code is not working as it should.

I am running this on an Ubuntu 12.04 Server installation with PHP 5.3.

Can someone explain me what is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a really weird behavior of `setIdAttribute` method. For some odd reason this method must be called even number of times. I'm not sure it's consistent across different  versions of PHP though. In my case (5.5.13) this works:

<kbd>Version 1: working</kbd>

```
$dom = new SMHtmlDocument();
$p1 = $dom->bodyAdd('p')->attr('id','foo');
$p = $dom->getElementById('foo');
echo $dom->saveHTML();
var_dump($p);

$p2 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
$p = $dom->getElementById('foo');
var_dump($p);

// let's see if both paragraph elements are the same
var_dump($p1->isSameNode($p2));
```

This works as well:

<kbd>Version 2: working</kbd>

```
$dom = new SMHtmlDocument();
$p1 = $dom->bodyAdd('p')->attr('id','foo');
$p1->setIdAttribute('id', TRUE);
$p1->setIdAttribute('id', TRUE);
$p = $dom->getElementById('foo');
echo $dom->saveHTML();
var_dump($p);

$p2 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
$p = $dom->getElementById('foo');
var_dump($p);

// let's see if both paragraph elements are the same
var_dump($p1->isSameNode($p2));
```

And this doesn't:

<kbd>Version 3: broken</kbd>

```
$dom = new SMHtmlDocument();
$p1 = $dom->bodyAdd('p')->attr('id','foo');
$p1->setIdAttribute('id', TRUE);
$p = $dom->getElementById('foo');
echo $dom->saveHTML();
var_dump($p);

$p2 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
$p2->setIdAttribute('id', TRUE);
$p2->setIdAttribute('id', TRUE);
$p = $dom->getElementById('foo');
var_dump($p);

// let's see if both paragraph elements are the same
var_dump($p1->isSameNode($p2));
```

I think it's a bug of the underlying xml library, libxml2 probably.

Comment: Great idea doubling the setIdAttribute(), even though making thing even more weird. It worked for me too. But if you add a third call, it stops working. So you are right when you say we have to call this function an even number of times.